# Converting bytes to list not working as intended

Tags: python

I am trying to convert 'bytes' into an 'int' list. I looked up a few methods to do this. But whenever I do it, it ends up converting each individual index into an 'int'.

I've tried:

```
ciphertext = list(data)
```

and

```
ciphertext = [x for x in data]
```

As you can see, the resulting list is the same length as the bytes object! I wanted it to look at 'x8a' and realize that is 1 int, not 3 int's. Could you help me understand why this is happening?

[image]

Solved! I was just confused at the '505' size. Pycharm actually made it so that the size meant for each '/xab', not each individual character

Comment: Could you include the text version of `data`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In a byte string, `\x8a` is one character. It is just printed that way. Your code should be correct.

Comment: @iz_ ohh... so you're saying that the 'data' variable is actually much 'longer' than 505 characters?

Comment: \x8a is one character.your code is correct I think

Comment: Not exactly, say you have a `bytes` object `foo = b'\x01\x02\x03'`. The length is 3. There is just no way to type `\x01` on your keyboard, so you need 4 characters to type it. It is stored as 1 character. You also can't print it as 1 character, so you need 4 characters to print it.

Comment: Unprintable bytes in a byte string are displayed as escape codes.  `\x03` is the single byte value of 3, and shown as a byte string as `b'\x03'`.

Comment: I posted an answer so you can properly mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a byte string, `\x8a` is one character. It is just printed that way. Your code should be correct.

Say you have a `bytes` object `foo = b'\x01\x02\x03'`. The length is 3. There is just no way to type `\x01` on your keyboard, so you need 4 characters to type it. It is stored as 1 character. You also can't print it as 1 character, so you need 4 characters to print it.

Read more about escape sequences at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals. Follow the link and scroll down a bit for the table of escape sequences.

Comment: thanks again. But I noticed 1 extra thing: in my bytes variable 'data', it starts with b'lzb...' Before it starts doing the \x01 thing, it has those 3 characters lzb. Why is that so?

Comment: The ASCII values for those characters can be printed. Take a look at http://www.asciitable.com. Notice that something like `\x41` is the same as `A`

Comment: Gotcha! Makes sense. When I opened the ciphertext in vscode. it was mainly weird looking symbols